# Browsing vim latex-suite quickly

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I use Vim Latex-Suite for typing my Latex files. One of the features I like is the F9 shortcut inside \ref{} which helps me to browse a document with many sections/labels and find the theorem labels quickly.

Do you know of something similar in Vim or Latex Suite for general navigation, not just insertion of references?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's better to ask one specific question rather than an open ended one like this... This said, for navigation try `\lt`. This should display a list of the section in your document that you can use to quickly move between them. (At least it does for me and *I think* that I cannibalised this from Latex-Suite...actually, maybe this is from LatexBox...)

Comment: There are a lot of books on VIM that enlighten about general navigation. One cool way to navigate is also the EasyMotion plugin: http://vimawesome.com/plugin/easymotion